# why is effects.js from magento's installation of scriptaculous, conflicting with the lazy-load jquery plugin from Mike Tuupola

Tags: jquery, magento, lazy-loading, prototype, scriptaculous

I have overridden the base default's page.xml, to include:
the jquery lazy load plugin as the first jquery script in the head section.
then immediately following that, i have a no_conflict.js that just contains:

```
var $jq191= jQuery.noConflict();
```

then page.xml has all the other javascript frameworks, like prototype and effects.js, dragdrop.js, etc.

Now I had originally implemented my site without magento, and using the lazy load plugin. with the lazy load plugin, I added a fadein effect when images load. it works fine without magento,
once I added magento, there was a terrible flicker when the images faded in, that only happened in google chrome. since i knew this happened with magento, I removed scripts included from magento one by one, and found out, that once I removed effects.js, the problem was solved.

Effects.js is a lot to swallow, and I'm new to jquery/javascript, so I was wondering if someone could shed some light on this issue. any help, would be greatly appreciated. thank you.

from page.xml:

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/no_conflict.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/menu.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>

            <block type="page/js_cookie" name="js_cookies" template="page/js/cookie.phtml"/>

            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>

            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
        </block>
```

from no_conflict.js:

```
var $jq191= jQuery.noConflict();
```

from local.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout>
    <default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/jquery.lazyload.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/loadlazy.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/jquery.fancybox-media.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/jquery.fancybox.css</stylesheet></action>
    </reference>
    </default>
    </layout>
```

from loadlazy.js:

```
$jq191(document).ready( function( evt ){

$jq191("img.lazy").lazyload({effect: "fadeIn"});
$jq191(".product-popup").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    type: 'iframe',
    helpers : { overlay : { locked : false,
                 } }
});
});
```

from accessories.phtml:

just setting class to "lazy" on img tags:

```
 <img style="display: block; position:absolute; top: 50%; left:50%; 
                                                            margin-left:<?php echo strval(-1*intval( $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->getOriginalWidth())/2); ?>px; 
                                                            margin-top:<?php echo strval(-1*intval($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->getOriginalHeight())/2); ?>px" 
                                                            class="lazy" id="lazy.images#<?php echo $_iterator; ?>"
                                                            src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl("img/product-placeholder.png"); ?>"
                                                            data-original="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image'); ?>" 
                                                            height="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->getOriginalHeight(); ?>" 
                                                            width="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->getOriginalWidth(); ?>" 
                                                            alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'image'), null, true); ?>" />
```

Comment: Can you add the code that is being called to the question. I think I have a solution - but I need to see what you are calling to be sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK here is the problem - and I'll give you a few solutions to your problem

```
jquery.lazyload.js
```

triggers an event called "appear" - and because of the way the jQuery `trigger()` method is written it will try and trigger a method on the element as well as trigger the event. The Effects methods in Scriptaculous add an `appear()` method to the Element prototype. The Scriptaculous `appear()` is firing as well as the lazyload `fadeIn()` and thats were you get a flicker when 2 methods are trying to change the opacity of the element at the same time.

**Easy Fix**

In your copy of effects.js the last line is

```
Element.addMethods(Effect.Methods);
```

If you remove that line it will remove the Scriptaculous Effects methods from the Element prototype and should fix the immediate problem. However if any other plugins are depending on the Effects methods on the Element prototype they will start failing. But if you are using those methods you can change them over to use the anonymous methods. ie

```
$('myelement').appear();
// changes to
Effect.Appear('myelement');
```

**Hard Fix**

In your copy of

```
jquery.lazyload.js
```

Look for the "appear" trigger and `observe()`/`on()` of the appear event and change the event name to something else - this will require more debugging as it might not work the first time. Also make sure you find all of the instances so everything is changed.